# Why do I need the visited state in Breadth First Search?

Tags: algorithm

I've implemented a breadth first search algorithm (actually, it's breadth first traversal because I'm not searching for any particular node, simply printing out the node values in the order they are visited) and haven't used any state tracking of each node - i.e. I haven't marked any node as visited. In most BFS implementations I see this notion of marking a node as visited so that you never visit it twice, but in my implementation I can't see any case where this would be possible.

Could someone explain why the visited state is ever useful and/or necessary?

Here's my implementation:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

public class BFS {

    public static void printTree(Node root) {
        Queue<Node> queue = new LinkedList<Node>();
        queue.add(root);
        while(queue.isEmpty() == false) {
            Node curr = queue.remove();
            System.out.println(curr.getValue());
            if (curr.getLeft() != null) {
                queue.add(curr.getLeft());
            }
            if (curr.getRight() != null) {
                queue.add(curr.getRight());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node leaf1 = new Node(5);
        Node leaf2 = new Node(6);
        Node leaf3 = new Node(7);
        Node leaf4 = new Node(7);
        Node leaf5 = new Node(11);
        Node rightRightRoot = new Node(12, leaf4, leaf5);
        Node leftRoot = new Node(1, leaf1, leaf2);
        Node rightRoot = new Node(9, leaf3, rightRightRoot);

        Node root = new Node(4, leftRoot, rightRoot);
        printTree(root);
    }

    static class Node {
        private int value;
        private Node left, right;

        public Node(int value, Node left, Node right) {
            this.value = value;
            this.left = left;
            this.right = right;
        }

        public Node(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public Node getLeft() {
            return left;
        }

        public Node getRight() {
            return right;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Most BFS implementations you`ve seen traverse arbitrary graphs and you travel through the tree. The difference in those two cases are **cycles**. Arbitrary graph can have them and states are necessary for not putting the node into the queue twice, but in your case you may live without them.

Answer (score 0):

Your code makes reference to a tree. By definition, a tree can't have cycles, so you are right that you don’t need to track if vertices have been visited if you are traversing a tree. A graph can have cycles, so it enables multiple vertices to be legitimate parents of a vertex.

For example, with a graph of four vertices (A,B,C,D) and the following topology:

```
 A
/ \
B C
\ /
 D
```

If a breadth-first search is started from A, both B & C can reach D. During execution, both B & C will add D to the queue, and thus it will be visited and printed twice.

The following code will print 4 twice:

```
Node D = new Node(4);
Node C = new Node(3, D, null);
Node B = new Node(2, null, D);
Node A = new Node(1, B, C);
printTree(A);
```